# htaccess redirect not working for some reason

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to figure out this code why it is not working

old url

```
 news.php?catID=text-from-database&nid=number-from-database
```

new url

```
 news-detail.php?cid=Cat-ID-Number&nid=number-from-database
```

or new url

```
 domain.com/number-from-database
```

I want to redirect permanently using below code. But it is not working.

```
Redirect 301 ^news.php?catID=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)&nid=([0-9]+) news-detail.php?cid=$1&nid=$2
Redirect 301 ^news.php?catID=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)&nid=([0-9]+) /$1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't match against the query string in a REDIRECT Directive. You need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` or `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable using Mod-rewrite:

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^catID=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)&nid=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news-detail.php?cid=%1&nid=%2 [L,R]
```

or :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /news\.php\?catID=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)&nid=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news-detail.php?cid=%2 [L,R]
```